# In C, can a function called Main() be created?

Tags: c, program-entry-point, case-sensitive, uppercase

Can a function called `Main()`, with a capital *M*, be created in C?
Since two elements with the same name but different cases are treated as separate entities, in my opinion `Main()` can be created but I just need to confirm.

Comment: Why don't you try?

Comment: I would go for `maiN()`

Comment: Well, this was on a mid-term test for C!

Comment: I've come across C code that does exactly this.

Answer (score 4):

Sure, why not? The preprocessor and compiler do not care that `"Main"` and `"main"` are *substantially similar*. C is case-sensitive, therefore `"Main"` and `"main"` are two completely different names. (it may not help readability, but there is no technical reason you can't) E.g.,

```
#include <stdio.h>

int Main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++)
        printf (" %2d : %s\n", i, argv[i]);

    return argc;
}

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    printf ("\n %d arguments.\n", Main (argc, argv) - 1);

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/mainMain The quick brown fox jumps over a lazy dog.
  1 : The
  2 : quick
  3 : brown
  4 : fox
  5 : jumps
  6 : over
  7 : a
  8 : lazy
  9 : dog.

 9 arguments.
```

Answer (score 2):

```
int Main (void)
{
   return 0;
}

int main (void)
{
   return 0;
}
```

Compiles und links perfectly. It is case-sensitive.

Comment: Thanks! I'm still a beginner; what do you mean by 'it links fine'? Both functions are within the same file, aren't they? Sorry if this is a terribly stupid question.

Comment: Yes, both functions in the same file. You have the compiler that translates the source to object-code. The linker puts it all together to have an executable. If you have more than one file it will link them together and also with some libraries of the system (e.g. for IO, ...). Depending on your environment both steps are done automatically if you try to create the executable.

Comment: One more to say: If you create a 2nd file and put the non-standard Main into it, then the linker will bring you an error "multiple definition of Main". Just to see the linker doing his job. It is not part of your question.

Answer (score 1):

It's terrible idea and some environments that aren't strictly conforming might reserve that name. But the linker is supposed to be case sensitive and Main with a capital is not reserved.

Comment: You mean the non-meticulous environments might reserve Main() as main() and not differentiate between the two?

Comment: Like Visual Studio reserves WinMain, at least in some modes. If a compiler needs an alternate entry with slightly different characteristics to main(), Main is an obvious choice of identifier.

Answer (score 1):

You have already got the answer, but just to add a bit of authoritative quotes, directly from `C11`, chapter §5.1.2

> Execution environments:
>
> Two execution environments are defined: freestanding and hosted. In both cases,
>   program startup occurs when a designated C function is called by the execution
>   environment.  [...]

then, §5.1.2.2, Hosted environment, p1, "Program startup"

> The function called at program startup is named `main`. [...]

That said, as we know, C is **case-sensitive**, (quoting §6.4.2.1/2, "Identifiers", General)

> An identifier is a sequence of nondigit characters (including the underscore _, the
>   lowercase and uppercase Latin letters, and other characters) and digits, which designates
>   one or more entities as described in 6.2.1. **Lowercase and uppercase letters are distinct.** [....]

so an identifier without the same case as `main()` is **not the same** as `main()`, be it `Main()`, `MAIN()`, `maiN()` or any other combination possible. They all are different identifiers as far as C is concerned.

So, the answer to

> *In C, can a function called Main() be created?*

is yes, certainly.

Just to clear up a bit more, if you **only** create `Main()` and leave out `main()`, compiler all by itself will have no way to know that you meant `main()` by writing `Main()`, since they are different identifiers to the compiler.

Comment: ".. as we already know .." – no need to refer to Wikipedia, as it's specifically mentioned in 6.4.2.1: "Lowercase and uppercase letters are distinct." :)

Comment: @RadLexus Well then, let me change that wiki to standard quote.. :)

Comment: That's *way* better than "why not" :D

Answer (score 0):

Only if you write one or more of its letters in uppercase, I think , Like Main or MAIN  otherwise your compiler won't be able to tell which main you want because main is already a function in C. 
Note: I am a beginner too so I could well be wrong.